# git push do nothing？

Tags: git, github

Now, I develop a IOS project, in this project, I use the `git submodule` command to add Alamofire project to my project, when I finished my project, use the `git push` command to push the project to my github.

All the commands have no error, but in my github the project file is empty, anybody knows why? Please forgive my poor english !

[git command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1OCq.jpg)

[the black file is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwVR1.jpg)

Comment: What is defined in 'remote' `git remote -v`?

Comment: Did you commit before trying to push?

Comment: What does `git status` show?

Answer (score 0):

Before you can push you have to add the content to stage and then to push it.

```
git add .
git commit ...
git push
```

If you are working on the code of the submodule you have to it all form within the submodule folder.

The root folder "does not" see any changes made to the submodule folder.

Comment: I have done these and no errors. But in my github webpage, the project file is empty. I try the other projects with no submodule and it works.